# can LinearLayout orientation be a number

Tags: android-linearlayout

Im working on developing a UI for an app, while refering examples I came across a piece of code

`<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="1" 
        android:id="@id/LinearLayout1" 
        android:layout_width="-1" 
        android:layout_height="-1" 
        android:keepScreenOn="true">`

in this block the orientation is set as 1, which i didn't understand is it vertical or horizontal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android documentation for [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html)

```
HORIZONTAL
```

is [constant value: 0](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#HORIZONTAL) and

```
VERTICAL
```

is [constant value: 1](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#VERTICAL)

Hope is answers your question.

**NOTE**: Please read documentation